# spring3 + mybatis custom typeHandler

Tags: spring, mybatis, typehandler

i have a pojo with some field of type `Set<String>`.
I want to persist them in the db as json, so i create a custom typeHandler, but when i try to persist i get the error: There was no TypeHandler found ....

```
 testSave(it.infora.suap.service.MailMessageServiceTest): nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: There was no TypeHandler found for parameter recipients_to of statement it.infora.suap.persistence.MailMessageMapper.insertEmailMessage
```

the parameter recipients_to in a `Set<String>`

this is my custom typeHandler class:

```
public class SetTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Set<String>>{


    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int columnIndex, Set<String> parameter, JdbcType jt) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(columnIndex,  serializeToJson(parameter));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return deserializeFromJson(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return deserializeFromJson(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return deserializeFromJson(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    private String serializeToJson(Set<String> parameter){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(parameter);
    }

    private Set<String> deserializeFromJson(String value){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Set<String>>(){}.getType();
        Set<String> result  = gson.fromJson(value, collectionType);

        return result;       
    }

}
```

what's wrong?  I'm using annotated mapper interface instead of mapper.xml

Thanks

Andrea

Comment: Is possible to see the xml where you use your typeHandler?

Comment: i don't have mapper.xml .... i'm using annotated mapper class. I created other custom typeHandler for managing enum type field and they are called automatically during insert operation

Comment: And what about applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: i posted my configuration in another post. You can find it here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218241/error-autowiring-service-in-test-using-spring-3-junit-4-mybatis)

Comment: Try add @MappedTypes(Set.class) as first line in your type handler

Answer (score 4):

I found some information [here](http://fzilic.github.com/Grails-MyBatis/guide/6%20Custom%20TypeHandlers.html) and [here](http://mybatis.github.com/mybatis-3/configuration.html), but it seems that you missed

```
@MappedTypes(Set.class) 
public class SetTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Set<String>>{
```

Comment: i tryed but it doesn't solve.... now i have this exception   `testSave(it.infora.suap.service.MailMessageServiceTest): nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'SetTypeHandler.class'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: SetTypeHandler.class`

Comment: this is the query in my mapper class     `@Insert("INSERT INTO mail_message(sender, receive_date, send_date, text, attachments, recipients_to, recipients_cc, recipients_bcc, subject, mailId) VALUES(#{sender}, #{receiveDate}), #{sendDate}), #{text}), #{attachments}, #{recipients_to, typeHandler=SetTypeHandler.class}, #{recipients_cc, typeHandler=SetTypeHandler.class}, #{recipients_bcc, typeHandler=SetTypeHandler.class}, #{subject}, #{mailId})")
    @Options(keyProperty = "id", useGeneratedKeys = true, flushCache = true)
    public void insertEmailMessage(MailMessageBean emailMessage);`

Comment: try to add the complete path for SetTypeHandler. Ex: it.project.typehandlers.SetTypeHandler.class

Comment: What about your problem..?

Comment: solved thanks ... in fact it required the full path for the Handler class when passed in the annotation  `..."#{recipients_bcc, javaType=java.util.Set,jdbcType=VARCHAR,typeHandler=it.infora.suap.handler.SetTypeHandler} ...`